# How to rename a file while it is being copied and copy complete

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to create a script which should copy files from one folder to another.

Since a file can be of a large size, of up to 1000 MB, it may take few seconds 
or a minute to completely copy it. While this is being happened, I want the filename  in a destination folder to be prefixed with an underscore(_).

Once the file is completely copied over to a destination folder, then the `_` should be removed from the filename. The purpose of doing this is to make sure that another process should not pick up the incomplete file from the destination folder.

How can we do this using a batch script? Currently my batch file is copying and moving the file to another folder but I don't know how can i prefix underscore and then remove again from the filename after the file is completely moved.

Here is my 2 line code which is copying and moving the file.

```
copy %1\Customer_*.xml C:\Users\ard\Documents\Folder1
move %1\Customer_*.xml %1\Archive
```

If this can't be done using batch script, then VB script should also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want, in words:

For each affected file in `C:\source`:

- Copy file `x` to `C:\destination\_x`
- Rename file `C:\destination\_x` to `C:\destination\x`

and in Windows batch code, with a few extras:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "SOURCE=%1"
set "DESTINATION=C:\Users\ard\Documents\Folder1"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (`dir /b "%SOURCE%\Customer_*.xml"`) do (
    if exist "%DESTINATION%\%%x" (
      echo %%x - already exists at destination
    ) else (
      echo %%x
      copy "%SOURCE%\%%x" "%DESTINATION%\_%%x" > NUL && rename "%DESTINATION%\_%%x" "%%x"
    )
)
```

Notes:

- the `for` loop can iterate a command's output line-wise
- in our case, that command is `dir /b "%SOURCE%\*.xml"`, i.e. the "bare" list of matching files in the source folder
- `usebackq` means the command is delimited by backticks, which allows using double quotes inside the command itself
- `delims=` sets the field delimiters to "none", otherwise `for` would split each filename into tokens if it contained spaces
- `> NUL` suppresses the "1 file(s) copied." success messages from `copy`
- `&&` means that `rename` is only executed if `copy` was successful

Comment: @joeking That's kind of like not a complete question.

Comment: OK, what happens if copy or rename fails? If copy fails its sortof OK, but it won't tell you which file failed. If rename fails it will leave the temporary file there and won't tell you which file failed.

Comment: @joeking Well... I figured I've added way to many bells and whistles already. I really did not want to go into batch error handling on top of what I already did, because it's out of scope for the question. I didn't want this to become a batch 101. (Realistically: If rename fails for a file you have just successfully copied, something is seriously wrong and you might have bigger problems at hand than a batch file that does not finish without errors)

Comment: Good point. A possibility is a duplicate in the destination, but the script checks for that ahead of time so it seems unlikely.

Comment: Could happen if two instances run in parallel, though. It is possible to make this bulletproof, but at the expense of readability.

Answer (score 2):

Removing a prefix is not trivial, but removing a suffix (new extension) is simple. So I would append a new extension like `.inProgress`. You can then COPY and RENAME a collection of files with two simple commands using wildcards.

But the MOVE command does not allow renaming multiple files, so a FOR loop would be required. I'll show the code, but I don't think it is really necessary in the OP's scenario. It looks to me like the source and destination folders are on the same drive, so the move should be virtually instantaneous, and there should be no need to use a temporary intermediate name.

```
copy "%1\Customer_*.xml" "C:\Users\ard\Documents\Folder1\*.*.inProgress"
ren "C:\Users\ard\Documents\Folder1\*.inProgress" *.

for %%F in ("%1\Customer_*.xml") do (
  move "%%F" "%1\Archive\%%~nxF.inProgress"
  ren "%1\Archive\%%~nxF.inProgress" *.
)
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for information on why the rename works.

Note that all the copied files will show up as ".inProgress" until the entire COPY operation has completed. If you want each file to be available as soon as possible, then a FOR loop is needed for the COPY as well:

```
for %%F in ("%1\Customer_*.xml") do (
  copy "%%F" "C:\Users\ard\Documents\Folder1\%%~nxF.inProgress"
  ren "C:\Users\ard\Documents\Folder1\%%~nxF.inProgress" *.
)
```

Comment: Nice solution, I like it.

Comment: @Tomalak - Except I had a bug! MOVE does not allow you to rename multiple files with wildcards. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ah, details. ;) My comment still applies, though.

Answer (score 1):

My example copies from src to dest with a new name, then restores back the old name:
bn is the basename of the source file.

```
for %%a in (src\*.xml) do (
set bn=%%~nxa
copy %%a dest\!bn!_
rename dest\!bn!_ !bn!
)
```

Comment: `set bn=%%~nxa` would be better (it would also remove the dependency on `enabledelayedexpansion`)

Comment: This still requires "setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION". The "bn" variable isn't needed - get rid of that and you don't need delayed expansion

Comment: Also, no error handling. For example:     copy %%a dest\%%~nxa > nul || (echo FAILED! %%a & exit /b 1)